# Custom page php style css and images do not work

Tags: php, css, osclass, custom-pages

I am developing a site from osclass. I have created custom pages, but they do not carry the css style nor the images. The js and php css file are in the same folder. The files and images exist and are there. But the Chrome Developer Console is reporting the 404 error. All files are in this path:

C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ oc-content \ themes \ osclasswizards \

Ex:
PHP file path "page-launches.php"
C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ oc-content \ themes \ osclasswizards \ page-launches.php

Css file path "style.css"
C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ oc-content \ themes \ osclasswizards \ style.css

Comment: What are the filenames of the files that you posted here? And are you sure that "css_p/style.css" actually exists? This is a relative URL, so the php file needs to be in the same folder where the css_p folder is located (not inside css_p - the php file and css_p should be in the same parent folder)

Comment: Please provide a better folder/file structure. where is located the main php file you have posted?

Comment: Also, check for example Chrome's dev console under the network tab to see if any files are not loaded (404 error or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the information. cjs1978, They are in the same folder, until I returned a folder in my style.css file, leaving it in css and php in the same folder, but it also did not work.The files and images exist and are there. But the development console of Chrome accuses in all the files the damn 404 error, (is in the following photos).[erros Chrome development console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egX8E.jpg)

Juan I. Morales Pestana, the structure of the folders / files is as follows:

PHP file path "page-lancamentos.php"
C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ oc-content \ themes \ osclasswizards \ page-lancamentos.php

Css file path "style.css"
C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ oc-content \ themes \ osclasswizards \ css_p \ style.css

Thanks a lot for the help.